# Django and ajax to update database without page refresh

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I want a button click to result in my database being updated without a page refresh. I've researched this a lot, and it seems a jquery ajax call is the way to go. But it's not working. I put a check in to see if the click event is working, and the strange thing is that it only works when I click the first button in the table (the table shows all the user's words with a 'for loop'). But then I get a 404 error, so it makes me think that my mistake is in my views? Nothing happens when I click the other words - no error, no click event, nothing. But everything works (i.e. the database gets updated) without using jquery, but then of course the page updates every time. By clicking the button the word should automatically get added to the user's word list without a page refresh. I'm stuck with this, would really appreciate some help, thanks!

**So I need to find out: 1) how to get the click event working every time; 2) how to get the url right in js; and 3) how to get my view right.**

My template (without jquery):

```
 <a id="add_word" href="{% url 'vocab:add-custom' word.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Add</a>
```

My template (with jquery):

```
<a id="add_word" href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Add</a>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var wordpk = "{{word.pk}}";
      </script>
```

My url:

```
app_name='vocab'
    
        path("<int:object>/",views.custom_create_word,name="add-custom"),
```

My view:

```
 def custom_create_word(request, object):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                pass
            if request.method =="GET":
                from .forms import WordForm
                from .models import Word
                word = Word.objects.get(pk=object)
                user = request.user
                target_word = word.target_word
                source_word = word.source_word
                deck_name = "My Words"
                fluency = 0
                Word.objects.create(user=user, target_word=target_word,
                                     source_word=source_word, deck_name=deck_name, fluency=fluency)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vocab:dict'))
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_word").click(function() {
      alert('click is working');
      $.ajax({
            url: "/vocab/"+wordpk+"/",
            success: function (result) {
              $("#add_word").html(result);
              alert("it worked");
            }});
          });
        });
```

**UPDATE**
My template:

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
          {% for word in dict_list %}
          <td>{{word.target_word}}</td>
          <td>{{word.source_word}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="javascript:" class="add-word btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-wordpk="{{word.pk}}">Add</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Just show us more code. How are you looping in template. And your table too

Comment: I think the issue is that the <a/> link gets added to the page after your script.

Comment: Also, if you have several elements with the same ID, js will never know which one you are referring to. And did you just declared global `wordpk` many times on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has to be something like this:

```js
 <a href="javascript:" class="add_word btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-wordpk="{{word.pk}}">Add</a>
```

and then

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add_word").click(function() {
      var wordpk = $(this).data('wordpk');
      $.ajax({
            url: "/vokab/"+wordpk,
            success: function (result) {
              $("#add_word").html(result);
              alert("it worked");
            }});
          });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The click is now working for every button, but I'm getting a 404 error for all of them. I'll post more code...

Comment: @MeL It seems to me the problem is your base URL, see my updated answer and see if this will generate the correct one.

Comment: Please, post the URL that is fired and the URL that is expected to fire `{% url 'vocab:add-custom' word.pk %}`

Comment: I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/%2Fvocab/dictionary/%7B%%20url%20'vocab:add-custom'%20%%7D550/ and it's supposed to be http://127.0.0.1:8000/vocab/550

Comment: I am still getting a 404 error, even though the url is now what I expect it to be.

Comment: I got it to work when I added %2F before vocab. It's great that it's working now, but I was just wondering why that %2F is needed? Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @MeL `%2F` is a HTML entity of forward slash `/` and it shouldn't be required. I would strongly recommend you try var_dumping `{% url 'vocab:add-custom' word.pk %}`, I think the problem lies in declaration of the URL.

Comment: How do I do that with Python? And where, in the shell? Will it cause problems later on if I leave `%2F` in?

Comment: How to do this with many classes?

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer for your **first** question.

Your click event was working only one time because you are using **id**, which is unique in the whole document. So, if you add click event on **id**, then only the first id element will work. But, html is forgiving language so, you won't see any html error if you use id in document more than once. You can validate and see if your html is fine or not from [w3c Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). Also, see [id attributte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

So, solution is simple. You can use **class** selector to check for onclick event. Like:

```
<a id="add_word" href="{% url 'vocab:add-custom' word.pk %}" class="add_word btn btn-warning btn-sm">Add</a>
```

Now, you have added `add_word` in class, I can select all the elements with the same class. In jquery:

```js
$(".add_word").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();       // To prevent default function of anchor tag
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks! So it would be better to use a class for this?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Also, see the second answer to store ```wordpk``` for each ```add_word``` button.